# JavaFx get regular Y-Axis TickUnit

Tags: javafx-2

- I want to stop Y-Axis autoRange , `yAxis.setAutoRange(false)`.
- I have `Maximum` Values. suppose `Minimum = 0`,
- How can i generate regular value for tickunit by using (max).
- To be able to.

  Y-axis.setUpperBound(max);
  Y-axis.setTickUnit(tickunit);

Comment: What do you mean by "regular"?

Comment: @Alexander Kirov like autorange but i have pagination over the chart and i want to fix y-Axis range over all pages.